# Imprimir en Genexus desde Chrome

Tags: genexus, print

Quiero colocar un boton que diga "imprimir" y mande al print del navegador lo que tiene la ventana actual que esta mostrando el sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrías hacer agregando un Textblock y un botón.

En el evento Start agregas el siguiente código:

```
Textblock.Format = 1
Textblock.Visible = 0
```

y en el botón:

```
Textblock.Caption = '<script> window.print(); </script>'
```